# Is there a way to have a smart contract pay for its own invocation?

Tags: tokens, gas, nft

I want to introduce people to Ethereum (and clones) by way of giving them an NFT related to an event we are organising. I realise most people don't have an Ethereum (or any other EVM compatible blockchain) balance, so I created a web server where I hosted a faucet that gives just enough to execute the NFT mint function.

Of course I had to implement rate limiting and so on to prevent the faucet to be drained immediately. I don't want to do this, and I don't want to keep the web server running for the 3 people that haven't claimed their NFT yet.

Is there a way to have a smart contract function pay for its own gas fee?

Note: This is executed on the Energy Web Chain, where 0.01 EWT is enough to mint an NFT.
Also: the NFT can be minted by redeeming a code of which we placed the hash on the blockchain.